# How can I embed custom raw HTML into a webpart

Tags: 2010, web-part, html

I am looking to add a codepen (http://codepen.io/) 'pens' into a site in my companies SharePoint.

When you create a new 'pen' in codepen, it gives you the option to embed the pen which ultimately gives you some HTML (note: not an iframe) but I want to simply add this into a page into SharePoint, but I am a little unsure how to do this, there doesnt seem to be a RAW HTML webpart (which would be great) that I can see.

How else could I do this?

Comment: There does exist a "RAW HTML" web part in SharePoint. It's called "HTML-Form Web Part". You can find it under the "Form" category when adding a web part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like codepen does allow iframe URLs, just not documented, so I used a page viewer web part and used the iFrame URL.

For those playing at home, this is the iframe URL format:

http://codepen.io/USERNAMEHERE/embed/PENIDHERE